# Encerrando qualquer conexao após "fechamento" do link

Tags: jquery, ajax

To usando um pequeno codigo ajax pra poder abrir alguns links! Só que as vezes nesses links tem alguns videos!! E até que carrega!! Só que o problema é que esses links sao abertos em um lightbox! E quando fecha o lightbox o video continua rodando!! O que é péssimo! Porque na verdade só fecha o lightbox! Não chega a "encerrar" o link!

Como que faz pra executar esse "encerramento" de link assim que fechar o lightbox?

Script do Lightbox

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lightbox').click(function(){
      $('.background, .box').animate({'opacity':'.9'}, 1, 'linear');
      $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 1, 'linear');
          $('.background, .box').css('display','block');
   }); 

   $('.close').click(function(){
          $('.background, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 1, 'linear', function(){
              $('.background, .box').css('display','none'); 
          });
    });
});
```

Código Ajax

```
  //Carregamento AJAX
  function pag(brl)
      {   
      var url = eval("brl");
      $( "#content" ).load(url, function(e) {
          e.preventDefault()
  });
      }
```

o Link é Assim:::

```
<a class="home lightbox" href="#!" onclick="pag('urlaseraerta.php');">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para perceber como resolver tens de perceber o que acontece quando fazes `click` no link e corres a função `pag('urlaseraerta.php')`.

O método `$( "#content" ).load` do jQuery vai buscar HTML à `url` que passaste como argumento da função e inserir esse HTML dentro do elemento que usaste no seletor em que usaste o método `.load()`.

Quando clicas para remover o link, o que estás a fazer é a esconder o elemento, mudando somente a sua visibilidade. Ou seja, o conteúdo continua lá, só que sem estar visível a utilizador.

O que precisas fazer é esvaziar essa div para o conteúdo desaparecer do DOM. Para isso basta juntares `.html('');` que substitui o conteudo por uma string vazia.

```
$('.close').click(function(){
      $('.background, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 1, 'linear', function(){
          $('.background, .box').css('display','none').html('');
          //                                          ^   ^   ^ - juntei aqui o que faltava
      });
});
```